# Thymleaf template result caching

Tags: java, ruby, spring, erb, thymeleaf

So I just seen this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhseQP52yIY

DHH talks about cache template results. I'm wondering if this a a thing in thymleaf.
The section about cache in the documentation is pretty slim.

As I read it it's only about caching the function generated for a template file.
Maybe I read it wrong.

Comment: I am not used to seeing this kind of wholesome Q&A interaction on SO.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a dialect extension at the time that allows caching of the resulting html. I hope it‘s what you looking for :)

https://github.com/Antibrumm/thymeleaf-extras-cache-dialect